# i can't understand how i change the value

Tags: assembly, gdb, gnu

im new to computer science, and im trying to solve a assembly debugging homework but its really complicated, i wanted to move to an another line of the code but i can't .

i tried to change the value of "PTR" using `set $PTR=10` that means that PTR is now greater than 9 but it didn't jump to the line `<+223>`, im using "gdb"

```
0x00000000000007c7 <+141>:  mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x48],0x0
   0x00000000000007ce <+148>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x48],0x9
   0x00000000000007d2 <+152>:   jg     0x819 <main+223>
```

it runs the lines one by one without jumping to the line `<+223>`

Comment: `PTR` is a keyword. There is nothing to change. You need to change the memory at address `rbp-0x48`. E.g. `set *(int*)($rbp-0x48)=10` or similar.